# how to build and run and delete executable file and dummy file in vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I want to build and run c++ source code. And then delete all except source code.

```
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "label": "g++ build active file",
      "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
      "args": [
        "-g",
        "${file}",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "&",
        "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "&",
        "rm ",
        "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "/usr/bin"
      },
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ],
  "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

I except they build and run and then delete worthless files, but it is not working.

Comment: In  a normal POSIX shell with job control, the single `&` means to create a job in the background. It's very different from the "logical" `&&` operator. My suggestion is that you read more about shells and how they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at [VScode tasks parameters](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks), you see that we can chain them with `dependsOn`. Note that the required `command` can contain the full path to where your tool is located when it's not included in your OS path variable, but `options.cwd` should contain the path to where your tool should run, i.e. `${fileDirname}`. Also you should study the `presentation` parameter and adjust it for the way you want to see errors.

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "label": "g++ build active file",
      "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
      "args": [
        "-g",
        "${file}",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
      ],
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "silent",
        "panel": "shared"
      },
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
      },
    },
    {
      "label": "cpp-run",
      "type": "process",
      "command": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
      "dependsOn": [
        "g++ build active file"
      ],
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always",
        "panel": "shared"
      },
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
      },
    },
    {
      "label": "cpp-test",
      "type": "process",
      "command": "rm",
      "args": [
        "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "cpp-run"
      ],
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "never",
        "panel": "shared"
      },
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
      },
    }
  ],
}
```