# How to build and execute cpp file in vscode ctrl+shift+B

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

**tasks.json**

```js
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
        "command": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "args": ["-g", "${file}", "-o", "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"],
        "options": {
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        }
      },{
        "label": "Run task...",
        "type": "process",
        "command": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "windows": {
          "command": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        },
        "group": "build",
        "options": {
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "dependsOn":[
          "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

I went through [how to build and run and delete executable file and dummy file in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55887333/how-to-build-and-run-and-delete-executable-file-and-dummy-file-in-vscode)  and wrote the above script to build and run `.cpp` files.

Although, `.cpp` files are being compiled into `.exe` but it's not running with the above command.

To, run `.exe` file i need to run manually by typing this `./path_to_file.exe` in the terminal.

It's running fine, but i would like run the file when i press `ctrl+shift+B`.

Comment: ctrl+shift+B is a Build shortcut, it does not run anything. Maybe you want F5?

Comment: Actually i would like to build and run the current `.cpp` file by one command.

Comment: Is this possible?